# CefSharp shows a blank page when run outside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cefsharp

I'm trying to create a C# class library which consists of a form with CefSharp WinForms browser inside it. The library is used by another application as a plugin. The application is set to run when pressing "start" in Visual Studio. Launching the application this way works fine and CefSharp browser shows up and works as it should.

The problems begin when I try to launch the application from the filesystem. This time the form opens, as well as the DevTools, but the CefSharp browser won't appear and the DevTools form/window is blank. The applications trace files show that the it indeed does load the CefSharp DLLs:

`15.56.32.202 Requested assembly CefSharp.WinForms (version 51.0.0.0) LOADED from file C:\*PATH_TO_THE_FILES*\CefSharp.WinForms.dll (version 51.0.0.0)

15.56.32.205 Requested assembly CefSharp (version 51.0.0.0) LOADED from file C:\*PATH_TO_THE_FILES*\CefSharp.dll (version 51.0.0.0)

15.56.32.243 Requested assembly CefSharp.Core (version 51.0.0.0) LOADED from file C:\*PATH_TO_THE_FILES*\CefSharp.Core.dll (version 51.0.0.0)`

The same trace file logs all thrown exceptions and in this case there are none.

Some other things to note:
- I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
- I'm building this for an x64 CPU.
- I've tried both Debug and Release built files, both work through VS and both fail without VS
- I've made sure I have all the files mentioned [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)) in the folder where from CefSharp is loaded
- I have Microsoft Visual C++ redists installed (11.0, 12.0, 14.0)
- Also tried including the msvcp120.dll & msvcr120.dll and their debug variants in the output folder (just in case).
- I've tried both CefSharp versions 51 and 57, behavior stays the same

My only guess is that, under the hood, Visual Studio includes references to some vital files/components/dlls/whatever that are not there when launching without it.

### UPDATE

I tried debugging this further and attached methods to following events:
LoadingStateChanged
ConsoleMessage

I created a test html page running on localhost which just calls console.log() with a simple message. The message is written to trace by the method attached to ConsoleMessage and when running from VS it's written to trace as it should. Without VS, it's not.

The method attached LoadingStateChanged wrote to trace the value of IsLoading property of the second parameter LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e. Running with or without VS both wrote the same thing: first true and then false. The ConsoleMessage was logged between these lines in trace when running with VS.

Furthermore, I tried disabling hardware acceleration with:

`CefSettings settings = new CefSettings(); 
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1")`

but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, as I suspected, related to missing references.

Adding the files of the VS output directory (bin/x64/Debug) to the external application's executable folder solved the problem.